# HMAC algorithm implementation

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashcode

I wanted to understand the HMAC algorithm. So, I implemented it as a Jupyter Notebook with all intermediate steps being output to console. My objective now is to improve it so it may serve as a reference to anyone trying to implement or understand it.

The [Jupyter Notebook on github](https://github.com/lordloh/OPT_algorithms/blob/master/rfc2104.ipynb) is easier to read and I would like feedback on the notebook rather than the code below.

[Jupiter notebook on GitHub](https://github.com/lordloh/OPT_algorithms/blob/master/rfc2104.ipynb)

```
import hashlib
import hmac

### Define key, message, Block size, hashing algorithm    
hash_algo = "sha1"
B = 64
message = b'hello!'
key = b'key'

### hash () for an easy to read code
def hash(M):
    H = hashlib.new(hash_algo)
    H.update(M)
    b_hash = H.digest()
    return b_hash

### XOR Translation table
trans_5C = bytes((x ^ 0x5C) for x in range(256))
trans_36 = bytes((x ^ 0x36) for x in range(256))

### Zero pad key to block length B
K_zpad=key.ljust(B,b'\0')
# Xor with ipad and opad sequence
K_ipad=K_zpad.translate(trans_36)
K_opad=K_zpad.translate(trans_5C)

print("Key XOR ipad(0x363636...):\n"+K_ipad.hex())
print("\n\nKey XOR opad(0x505050...):\n"+K_opad.hex())

### concatinate message
part1=K_ipad+message
print("key XOR ipad || message:\n"+part1.hex())

### hash (key xor ipad || message )
hash1=hash(part1)
print("hash( key XOR ipad || message):\n"+hash1.hex())

### hash (key xor opad || hash ( (key xor ipad)||message ) )
part2 = K_opad + hash1
print("hash (key xor opad || hash ( (key XOR ipad)||message ) ):\n"+part2.hex())
hash_final = hash(part2)
print("\n\nFinal Hash:\n"+hash_final.hex())

# Compare with Python's HMAC Implementation
pyH=hmac.new(key,message,digestmod=hash_algo)
pyH.hexdigest()
```

Answer (score 1):

> My objective now is to improve it so it may serve as a reference to anyone trying to implement or understand it.

In light of that goal I would have thought it made more sense to use the documented test vectors of [RFC 2202](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2202.html) rather than make up your own one.

---

> ```
> ### hash (key xor opad || hash ( (key xor ipad)||message ) )
> part2 = K_opad + hash1
> print("hash (key xor opad || hash ( (key XOR ipad)||message ) ):\n"+part2.hex())
> hash_final = hash(part2)
> print("\n\nFinal Hash:\n"+hash_final.hex())
> ```

The comment and the first `print` *describe* `hash_final`, not `part2`. IMO this is a bug, albeit a minor one.

Comment: `hash_final = hash(part2)` what is wrong? The comment and print are expanding the part1 in part2 as `hash ( (key xor ipad)||message`

Comment: @LordLoh., what's wrong is `print("hash (`

Comment: I see. Thank you. I was unaware of RFC 2202. That is a good idea!